# kineticJS 5.1 and jquery.transformtool

Tags: kineticjs

I found this plug-in https://github.com/soloproyectos/jquery.transformtool  works great in KineticJS 4.7 but not 5.1; has anyone tried to use it with 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on porting it to 5.1.0 here: https://github.com/bennettw/jquery.transformtool Please help out if you can.

As far as upgrading a project from KineticJS 4.7 to 5.1, you will need to account for the following changes:

- Most getters and setters dropped the "get" and "set" portion of their name. Exceptions include `getAbsolutePosition()` and `getParent()`. (Technically this is optional because v5.1.0 still has the old style methods deprecated.)
- Kinetic.Group no longer has the width and height of its contained objects.
- All methods that took two x, y parameters now take an object `{ x: xval, y: yval }`. So `target.position(0, 0)` now becomes `target.position({x: 0, y: 0})`. `size()` also changed and expects an object with `width` and `height`.
- Degrees are now the default instead of radians. To use the 4.7 behavior use `Kinetic.angleDeg = false`. Read the background discussion on this change [here](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/743).

There are still a few more differences that I haven't figured out yet. I am setting the offset on a `Kinetic.Group`, but I am still seeing transforms based around the top left corner of the Kinetic object (which is the default).